# What will take the boolean variables by default?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, boolean

I know, boolean variables are NO by default.

```
BOOL first;
BOOL second;

if (first != second) {
    NSLog(@"Yes");
}else{
NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

The OutPut is :Yes

But when i assign NO to first and second, i got 'NO' out put.

```
first = NO;
second = NO;

if (first != second) {
    NSLog(@"Yes");
}else{
NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

The OutPut is: NO

Where is the problem? Or should boolean variables exactly take NO by default? Or Depending on compiler?

I have used Xcode 4.2 version. I don't understand where the problem is. Please explain any one with example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables are not initialized by default; you get random garbage in them. You should initialize them with `BOOL first = NO;` if you want them to have a reasonable value.

Comment: and this implies to all prog languages.

Comment: Additionally, running Product->Analyze from the Xcode menu gives a reasonable diagnostic message for this.

Comment: @samfisher This does not apply to all languages; it doesn't even apply to Objective-C for, say, static or instance variables.

Comment: aah... please dont take it literally. I ment similar languages c,c++ for variable declarations just like the one shown above in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C, like C, doesn't have a real type for Boolean. If you look at `/usr/include/objc/objc.h`, you'll find this:

```
#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

So your code is saying

```
if (0 != 0) {
   ...
}
```

which is never true.